# How do I allow the user to determine template type?

Tags: c++, templates, if-statement, linked-list, switch-statement

I wrote a working, linked-queue that is templated on it's datatype, however the user may be inputing data in one of a few different types. How can I select which datatype will be used at run-time?

It works fine if I use each type individually; I just need every possibility covered without changing code or re-writing overloaded functions for every data type.

Below I've provided the relevant pieces of my code. As I said, no problems with my class member functions.

I already have tried a switch statement that creates x type version of the queue, but that cannot work as later possibilities within the switch "contradict" with other queue data types. I am currently trying if/else if statements, with no errors other than when I try to use the input of x type, it says it is undefined.

```
// From Source.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "LQueue.h"
int mainMenu();
int main()
{
    int value;
    bool stop = false;
    Queue<int> *theQueue;
    int choice = mainMenu();

    if (choice == 1) {
        Queue<int> theQueue;
        int dataType;
    }
    else if (choice == 2) {
        Queue<double> theQueue;
        double dataType;
    }
    else if (choice == 3) {
        Queue<string> theQueue;
        string dataType;
    }
    else if (choice == 4) {
        Queue<char> theQueue;
        char dataType;
    }

    cout << "\n\nHow many items would you like to initially"
        << " populate the queue with? ";
    int howMany;
    cin >> howMany;

    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        cin >> dataType;
        theQueue.enqueue(dataType)
    }

    theQueue.display(cout);

    theQueue.dequeue();

    theQueue.display(cout);

    return 0;
}
```

```
int mainMenu()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "What type of data will you be storing in the queue?\n"
        << "1. integers\n2. decimal numbers\n3. words\n4. chars\n\n";

    cin >> choice;
    if (choice > 0 && choice < 5)
        return choice;

    cout << "\n\nInvalid choice\n\n";
    mainMenu();
}
```

```
// Guess I'll include shown functions from the Queue class file below

//--- Definition of enqueue()
template <typename QueueElement> 
void Queue<QueueElement>::enqueue(const QueueElement & value)
{
    if (empty())
    {
        myFront = myBack = new Node(value);
    }
    else
    {
        myBack->next = new Node(value);
        myBack = myBack->next;
    }
}

//--- Definition of dequeue()
template <typename QueueElement> 
void Queue<QueueElement>::dequeue()
{
    if (empty() == false)
    {
        Queue::NodePointer oldFront = myFront;
        myFront = myFront->next;
        delete oldFront;
    }
}

//--- Definition of display()
template <typename QueueElement> 
void Queue<QueueElement>::display(ostream & out) const
{
    Queue::NodePointer ptr;
    for (ptr = myFront; ptr != 0; ptr = ptr->next)
        out << ptr->data << "  ";
    out << endl;

}

//--- Definition of front()
template <typename QueueElement> 
QueueElement Queue<QueueElement>::front() const
{
    if (!empty())
        return (myFront->data);
    else
    {
        cerr << "*** Queue is empty "
            " -- returning garbage ***\n";
        QueueElement * temp = new(QueueElement);
        QueueElement garbage = *temp;     // "Garbage" value
        delete temp;
        return garbage;
    }
}
```

````
Compiler (visual studio 2017) is showing identifier "dataType" is undefined within the following loop:
```c++

    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        {
            cin >> dataType;
            theQueue.enqueue(dataType);
        }
````

2 errors: E0020 and C2065 on the "cin >> dataType;" line, and also another
C2065 on the next line

Maybe there is a more efficient way overall of doing this? I am open to any and all suggestions, thank you!

Comment: update: I added a typedef at the beginning of the main function.. and changed the variable declarations within the if's to typedefs as well... Works now, but I lose the data after the first display(); likely because I do not have multiple definitions for my assignment operator. For integer vars, works just fine.... Thanks already for those who have viewed lol xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (a problem) is that when you write

```
    if (choice == 1) {
        Queue<int> theQueue;
        int dataType;
    }
    else if (choice == 2) {
        Queue<double> theQueue;
        double dataType;
    }
    else if (choice == 3) {
        Queue<string> theQueue;
        string dataType;
    }
    else if (choice == 4) {
        Queue<char> theQueue;
        char dataType;
    }
```

you define four different `theQueue` and four different `dataType` variables that are, each one, valid only inside the corresponding body of the corresponding `if`.

So, when you write

```
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        cin >> dataType;
        theQueue.enqueue(dataType)
    }

    theQueue.display(cout);

    theQueue.dequeue();

    theQueue.display(cout);
```

there are no more `dataType` and `theQueue` available (all of they are out of scope).

I suggest something as follows

```
    if (choice == 1) {
        foo<int>();
    }
    else if (choice == 2) {
        foo<double>();
    }
    else if (choice == 3) {
        foo<std::string>();
    }
    else if (choice == 4) {
        foo<char>();
    }
```

where `foo()` is a template function almost like this (caution: code not tested)

```
template <typename T>
void foo ()
 {
   Queue<T> theQueue;
   T        dataType;

   std::cout << "\n\nHow many items would you like to initially"
        << " populate the queue with? ";
   int howMany;
   std::cin >> howMany;

   for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
      std::cin >> dataType;
      theQueue.enqueue(dataType)
    }

   theQueue.display(cout);

   theQueue.dequeue();

   theQueue.display(cout);
 }
```

Comment: so should foo() be defined within the header file since it is a template function?

Comment: @K.Rile - Maybe. Or also in the same cpp file where is called, if it's called **only** in that cpp file.

Comment: Awesome! your suggestion works marvelously! Thanks so much! 10/10 would ask again lol

Comment: I provide an alternative method that looks up the function by index

Answer (score 0):

Write a templated member function that does what you want:

```
template<class DataType>
void processInput(int howMany) {
    DataType value;

    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        cin >> value;
        theQueue.enqueue(value);
    }

    theQueue.display(cout);

    theQueue.dequeue();

    theQueue.display(cout);
}
```

#### Method 1 - switch statement

We can then use a switch statement to select between them in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    int choice = mainMenu();

    cout << "\n\nHow many items would you like to initially "
            "populate the queue with? ";
    int howMany;
    cin >> howMany;

    switch(choice) {
      case 1:
        processInput<int>(howMany);
        break;
      case 2:
        processInput<double>(howMany);
        break;
      case 3:
        processInput<string>(howMany);
        break;
      case 4:
        processInput<char>(howMany);
        break;
    }
}
```

#### Method 2 - array of methods

We can use an array to do a lookup!

```
using func_t = void(*)(int);

int main() {

    std::vector<func_t> options = {
        processInput<int>, 
        processInput<double>, 
        processInput<string>, 
        processInput<char>
    };

    int choice = mainMenu();

    func_t selectedOption = options[choice - 1]; 

    cout << "\n\nHow many items would you like to initially "
            "populate the queue with? ";
    int howMany;
    cin >> howMany;

    selectedOption(howMany); 
}
```